# How to divide my transactions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure which deletes a couple of million records and then re-inserts changed ones.

Right now I have organized my transactions thus:

```
begin tran - delete records - commit tran
begin tran - insert records - commit tran
```

I was wondering though whether the following might not be faster:

```
begin tran - delete records - insert records - commit tran
```

Because then it might recognize that the new records can take the place of the old ones, and thus be faster?

Comment: Why not just update the existing ones that are being replaced, or am I misreading you?

Comment: They are not the same ones, they differ in number and content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction boundaries should be based on the logic of what you are doing. In the first scenario you can potentially leave the database in the state that the old records are deleted but the new ones are not inserted. Is this acceptable? Can you recover? If not, then you should use the second scenario.

Comment: Thanks.. you are right, transactions are to ease rollback / recovery, not for speed.